# How to run a function in background in Node.js

Tags: node.js

I have a function to make entries into the database at random intervals of time. It calls itself recursively using random Timeouts.

But it at the moment of course interferes with the request/response cycle which is why I want it to be a background task.

How do I run a `function` in background in Node.js? I came across npm module `kue` but do not understand one bit how to use it to have this function run in background.

Edit: I created a file `bgTask.js` and moved this function there:

```
var randomstring = require('random-string');
var Thing = require('./thing.model');

  var autoCreate = function(){
  console.log("THING CREATED AUTOMATICALLY")
  var randomNumb=0;
    clearTimeout(randomNumb);

     randomNumb = (Math.random()* (10-5) + 5).toFixed(0);
    console.log("random number", randomNumb)
   var randomThing =randomstring({
  length: randomNumb,
  numeric: false,
  letters: true,
  special: false
});
   console.log("ranfom thing", randomThing)

   Thing.create({
    name: randomThing,
    readByUser: false 
  }, function(err, thing) {
    console.log("THING IS", thing)
      setTimeout(autoCreate, randomNumb * 1000);
    });

  }

setTimeout(autoCreate, 10*1000);
```

It looks like above.

In my controller file of an API, I have this line of code:

```
var myBgTask = require('child_process').fork('./bgTask.js');
```

But I get an error that says:

```
Error: listen EADDRINUSE ::  5858
```

How do I fix this?

Comment: What type of interference are  you seeing with requests?

Comment: You could use [`child_process`](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html). `child_process.fork()` allows you to execute a .js file asynchronously.

Comment: @DavinTryon: I get connection error on post and put requests on client /end.

Comment: @ShanShan: Would you mind sharing an example that shows how to use child processes in this context?

Comment: It's easy, put the code you posted in a separate file (*bgTask.js* for example), then in your main file (*app.js*), you just have to `var myBgTask = require('child_process').fork('./bgTask.js')` and that's it. `myBgTask` allows you to communicate with the created child process (to get its output or to kill it).

Comment: @ShanShan: Could you please check the update in my question? I get an error.

Comment: That's the debugger, a node debugger is still running in the background, kill all node process or run your code without the debugger.

Comment: @ShanShan: Hey, I could fix that part. But there's still one problem. My function is not able to make database entries, the part where I am doing Thing.create. It getting stuck there. Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

You should not have to do this as a background task. I have a similar process where I periodically monitor the status of servers and update the db.

In a separate file I have a class like so:

```
export default class ServerManager {
    constructor(mongoServer, maxRestartAttempts = 5, restartTime = 60000, pollInterval = 5000) {
      ...
      this.pollInterval = pollInterval;
    }
    //...lots of other methods
    startMonitor() {
      console.log('Starting Server Monitor.');
      var self = this;
      this.intervalID = setInterval(self.monitorLoop.bind(this), self.pollInterval);
    }
}
```

The monitorLoop calls a series of methods one of which is:

```
checkServers() {
  // check if any servers are down
  for (var serverName in this.serversMap) {
    var server = this.servers[this.serversMap[serverName]];

    // todo improve handling of different states
    if (server.state !== 'running' &&
      server.shouldRestart &&
      server.status === 'ACTIVE' &&
      server.restartAttempts < this.maxRestartAttempts) {

      var now = new Date();
      if (now - server.restartTimeStamp > this.restartTime) {

        var update = {
          restartTimeStamp: now,
          restartAttempts: server.restartAttempts + 1,
          state: "restarting"
        };
        this.mongoServer.findById(server._id)
          .then(saveUpdates(update))
          .catch(handleError('Todo: Something bad happened here'));
        this.restartServer(server);
      } // end if (now - server.restartTimeStamp > this.restartTime)

    } // end if (server.state !== 'running' && ...
  } // end for (var serverName in this.serversMap)
} // end checkServer
```

Back over in my server.controller.js I have:

```
import ServerManager from './ServerManager';
let serverManager = new ServerManager(Server);
...
console.log('starting monitor');
Server.find({}).then(servers => {
    servers.forEach(server => {
      serverManager.addServer(server)
    })
  })
  .then(() => {
      serverManager.startMonitor();
    }
  )
  .catch((err) => console.log(err));
```

You can view my code here: https://github.com/MichaelLeeHobbs/roboMiner/tree/master/server/api/server

I realize this does not directly answer your question thus I will delete my answer if you really want to do this as a background task.